# How to better partition valid or invalid inputs

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

Given a list of inputs that could be valid or invalid, is there a nice way to transform the list but to fail given one or more invalid inputs and, if necessary, to return information about those invalid inputs? I have something like this, but it feels very inelegant.

```
def processInput(inputList: List[Input]): Try[List[Output]] = {
    inputList map { input =>
        if (isValid(input)) Left(Output(input))
        else Right(input)
    } partition { result =>
        result.isLeft
    } match {
        case (valids, Nil) => 
            val outputList = valids map { case Left(output) => output }
            Success(outputList)
        case (_, invalids) => 
            val errList =  invalids map { case Right(invalid) => invalid }
            Failure(new Throwable(s"The following inputs were invalid: ${errList.mkString(",")}")) 
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simplify your current solution quite a bit with standard scala:

```
  def processInput(inputList: List[Input]): Try[List[Output]] = 
    inputList.partition(isValid) match {
     case (valids, Nil) => Success(valids.map(Output))
     case (_, invalids) => Failure(new Throwable(s"The following inputs were invalid: ${invalids.mkString(",")}"))
  }
```

Or, you  can have a quite elegant solution with `scalactic`'s `Or`.

```
  import org.scalactic._

  def processInputs(inputList: List[Input]): List[Output] Or List[Input] = 
    inputList.partition(isValid) match {
     case (valid, Nil) => Good(valid.map(Output))
     case (_, invalid) => Bad(invalid)
  }
```

The result is of type `org.scalactic.Or`, which you then have to match to `Good` or `Bad`. This approach is more useful if you want the list of invalid inputs, you can match it out of `Bad`.

Answer (score 2):

scalaz's validation is designed exactly for this. Try reading the [tale of three nightclubs](https://gist.github.com/oxbowlakes/970717) for how this would work, but the body of your function would probably end up just consisting of something like:

```
def processInput(inputList: List[Input]): Validation[List[Output]] = {
  inputList foldMap { input =>
    if (isValid(input)) Failure(Output(input))
    else Success(List(input))
}
```